# Employer in Thailand

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, thailand

**Working in Thailand,having B1/B2 visa on my passport.

Can an employer take employees passport to the US embassy and get employees visa cancelled?
or 
Can my employer send someone else on my behalf with my passport to get my visa cancelled?
The employer cannot or can take an employees *passport* to the embassy to get the visa cancelled with or without employees permission?**

Comment: An employer typically has no business taking your passport or doing anything with it without your permission. Even if they did take your passport to the embassy, I think its unlikely that the embassy would do anything with it since its *your* passport and you're not there asking them to do anything.